# How to check if number from stdin is less than the numeric limit of a given type?

Tags: c++, types, precision

I have received a task that does not actually specify, what range of input one of my functions should expect (only, that it is always going to be a positive integer), and the input is decided runtime. Can I somehow test if the type I selected can actually hold the value it was fed to?

An illustration of what I am hoping to do:

```
char test;
std::cin >> test;
if(MAGIC)
{
    std::cout << "Error." << std::endl;
}
```

With the magical part (or even the preceeding line) being the test I'm looking for.
It should work like this:

> stdin: 100 -> no output
>
> stdin: 1000000 -> Error.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582509/why-does-integer-overflow-cause-errors-with-c-iostreams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most data types you can check the error state of the input stream as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582509/335858). However, this would not work for some other types, such as `char` from your post, because `std::cin >> test` would read data as a single character, i.e. `'1'` which is not what you need to achieve.

One approach is to read the number into `std::string`, and compare it to the `max()` obtained through limits:

```
std::string max = std::to_string(std::numeric_limits<char>::max());
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
bool cmp = (s.size() == max.size()) ? (s <= max) : (s.size() < max.size());
std::cout << s << " " << cmp << std::endl;
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/SWwAnL)

**Note:** The above code makes an assumption that the data entered is a number, which may be arbitrarily large, but must not contain characters other than digits. If you cannot make this assumption, use [a solution from this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4654636/335858) to test if the input is numeric.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer may be in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855465/7071399 to know where to get the limits, then refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574912/7071399 to get inspiration to your code (given you can use a long int or a char array to store the number and then check if it fits in the integer value).